# Codeception shows 502 bad gateway when running acceptance test with codecoverage

Tags: codeception

I tried using Codeception coverage for acceptance test for Yii2. The terminal command is this.

./vendor/bin/codecept run -c frontend acceptance --coverage-xml

The codeception versions are:

- c3: 2.0.14
- base: 2.4.0

Somewhat the webdriver ask selenium to access one page two times where the second one returns 502. The screenshot taken by codeception is also showing bad gateway. Here's the nginx log.

```
172.19.0.1 - - [15/Mar/2018:20:37:36 +0700]"GET /c3/report/clear HTTP/1.0" 200 0"-" "-" "-""0.002"
172.19.0.1 - - [15/Mar/2018:20:37:37 +0700]"GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 5"-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.167 Safari/537.36" "-""0.031"
172.19.0.1 - - [15/Mar/2018:20:37:37 +0700]"GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 8865"-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.167 Safari/537.36" "-""0.029"
172.19.0.1 - - [15/Mar/2018:20:37:37 +0700]"GET /login HTTP/1.1" 502 568"-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.167 Safari/537.36" "-""0.168"
```

Here's the nginx error log.

2018/03/15 20:44:17 [error] 24#24: *1098 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /login HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "localhost:7002"

And then here's the PHP error log. Although I'm not sure if this gives any problem.

```
[15-Mar-2018 20:45:29 Asia/Jakarta] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: settings in /srv/www/app/c3.php on line 244
[15-Mar-2018 20:45:29 Asia/Jakarta] PHP Stack trace:
[15-Mar-2018 20:45:29 Asia/Jakarta] PHP   1. {main}() /srv/www/app/frontend/web/index.php:0
[15-Mar-2018 20:45:29 Asia/Jakarta] PHP   2. require() /srv/www/app/frontend/web/index.php:11
[15-Mar-2018 20:45:29 Asia/Jakarta] PHP   3. __c3_factory() /srv/www/app/c3.php:330
[15-Mar-2018 20:45:29 Asia/Jakarta] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable:  settings in /srv/www/app/c3.php on line 245
[15-Mar-2018 20:45:29 Asia/Jakarta] PHP Stack trace:
[15-Mar-2018 20:45:29 Asia/Jakarta] PHP   1. {main}() /srv/www/app/frontend/web/index.php:0
[15-Mar-2018 20:45:29 Asia/Jakarta] PHP   2. require() /srv/www/app/frontend/web/index.php:11
[15-Mar-2018 20:45:29 Asia/Jakarta] PHP   3. __c3_factory() /srv/www/app/c3.php:330
```

Comment: Have you got a codeception.yml file in the same directory as c3.php ?

Comment: Yes, in the same directory.